# find out css selector of an element which gets active/appears by dragging other element over it

Tags: css-selectors, webdriver, firebug

I have left and right side of an HTML page. From left side I drag an element over right which makes the desired element appear on page. Now since I am holding element with mouse, simultaneously I can't right click over desired element to find it in console.

I am working on Widows 7, using Firebug which Firefox's Add on.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JavaScript controlled event that is causing the element to appear, you can use the *Break On Next* button ( [image: *Break On Next* button within Firebug] ) within the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel). That function allows you to stop the script execution at the next function call.

Depending on whether the HTML structure is changed you can also use the *Break On Mutate* button ( [image: *Break On Mutate* button] ) instead, or even the more fine grained control via the [context menu options *Break On Attribute Change* or *Break On Child Addition or Removal*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Context_Menu) within the *HTML* panel.

Using the functions above the script execution should halt when the element is displayed. You can then switch to the *HTML* panel and inspect the element there.

*Note: While the script execution is stopped you cannot use the Inspector feature. You have to navigate to the element within the HTML panel.*